# getting late initializer error in advance_pdf_viewer package

Tags: flutter, dart, pdf-viewer

I am fetching pdf note from the network. but it is showing late initialization error.
I removed the keyword late then it says `document` must be initialized.

```
import 'package:advance_pdf_viewer/advance_pdf_viewer.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/src/foundation/key.dart';
import 'package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart';

class NotesView extends StatefulWidget {
  const NotesView({Key? key, required this.noteId, required this.noteName})
      : super(key: key);
  final int noteId;
  final String noteName;

  @override
  State<NotesView> createState() => _NotesViewState();
}

class _NotesViewState extends State<NotesView> {


  late PDFDocument document;
//getting error at this linee ^^^


  loadDocument() async {
    await PDFDocument.fromURL(
        'http://www.africau.edu/images/default/sample.pdf');
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    loadDocument();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: Text("Note View")),
      body: Center(
          child: PDFViewer(
        document: document,
      )),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You created a variable named document and marked it late but never initialised the value of it.  In initState you can do this

```dart
loadDocument() async {
   document =  await PDFDocument.fromURL(
        'http://www.africau.edu/images/default/sample.pdf');
   setState((){});
  }
```

**Edit**

Change

```dart
late PDFDocument document;
```

To

```
PDFDocument? document;
```

And in build

```dart
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: Text("Note View")),
      body: Center(
          child: (document == null) ? 
         CircularProgressIndicator(): 
         PDFViewer(
           document: document!,
         )),
    );
```

Comment: I changed my code with yours but still getting the same error sir...

Comment: You may have to restart the app since it's in init state

Comment: I have restarted sir but ```Non-nullable instance field 'document' must be initialized.
Try adding an initializer expression, or a generative constructor that initializes it, or mark it 'late'.``` getting this error`

Comment: ```body: Center(
          child: PDFViewer(
        document: document,
      )),``` error => The argument type 'PDFDocument?' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'PDFDocument'.

Comment: after adding question mark

Comment: I tried with syncfusion pdf viewer but it did not show anything on the view page.

Comment: Edited my answer again. In build add document: document!. Add an exclamation for the second document